# Правильная работа с WCF службой через Клиент

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf, служба

Подскажите, как лучше реализовывать работу со службой через клиент?

Открывать 1 соединение при инициализации формы и передавать его между формами или

открывать соединения только при необходимости?(Открыл соединения, выполнил метод, закрыл соединение.)

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю в WCF нет такого понятия как соединение,по крайней мере я работал с ним по следующей схеме:
1) В клиентском приложении создается экземпляр класса клиента выбранной службы
2) Клиентское приложение производит поиск в сети запущенные службы заданного типа и получает его `Endpoint.Adress`и прокидывает его в экземпляр класса клиента
3) Выполняются нужные методы службы `client.SomeMethod(SomeParametr)`

Сама служба при этом не знает в какой момент обнаружили ее и когда клиентское приложение завершает свою работу. Если есть необходимость уведомлять об этом службу необходимо вызывать соответствующие методы, либо использовать периодическое пингование между клиентом и службой.

Клиент также не узнает о том что служба перестала существовать, пока не попытается обратиться к ней (решается пингованием)

Также по поводу обнаружения процесс обнаружения может занимать длительное время (около 30 секунд) так что смысла его делать более 1 раза мало. Если у вас более 1 активной службы единовременно, то после начального поиска можно сохранить не только выбранный `Endpoint.Adress`но и все остальные и переключатся между ними при необходимости

Comment: В WCF есть такое понятие как канал. Для некоторых биндингов (к примеру, NetTcpBinding) канал соответствует соединению, для других (HttpBinding) канал больше условность чем что-то реальное.

Comment: таких тонкостей не знал, работал только с `HttpBinding`